# How to subtract one day from current date then convert to string in Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

Here is the case. I'm trying to make select syntax to get data from last day (today we have 21.10 so as a result I should have data with 20.10 date query will be a part of ETL proces in Talend so I can't simply do `where date = '2016-10-20'`)
The problem is that all columns in data source are in VARCHAR or STRING type - date also. Source is on Hive Hadoop.

My code:

```
select 
cast(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dzien ,'yyyyMMdd'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')) as date),
count(ns_utc) as ILOSC_ODSLON
from portal.portal_data 
where
portal_data.opl_ev_ty is null 
and portal_data.opl_ev_as is null
and cast(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dzien ,'yyyyMMdd'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')) as date) = CAST(TO_DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()))as date) - interval '1' day

GROUP BY 
cast(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dzien ,'yyyyMMdd'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')) as date)
```

With that code query returns nothing exept columns name. The problem is probably with this part `= CAST(TO_DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()))as date) - interval '1' day`.

I made some tests. When I'm running this query

```
select CAST(TO_DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()))as date) - interval '1' day
```

result is `2016-10-20 00:00:00.0` and part 00:00:00.0 probably ruins my query, becasue when in main query instead of `= CAST(TO_DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()))as date) - interval '1' day` I'm putting condition `= '2016-10-20'` result is as expected.

Can you please guide me how to solve this problem?

Instead of Hue I'm using SQL Workbench

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your problem correctly. Minus number of seconds in a day(43200) from unix timestamp in where clause then try-CAST(TO_DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-43200))as date)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is the way you trying to subtract a day from date.I would suggest to subtract number of seconds in a day(86400) from unix timestamp in where clause-

```
CAST(TO_DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-86400))as date)
```

Comment: similar idea but keeping precision of the time. In this case i subtract one hour `cast( (cast(yourtimestampcolumn as bigint)-1*3600) as timestamp)`

Answer (score 25):

once you parsed the date then use `date_sub` function that is available in hive

```
date_sub(string startdate, int days) 

date_sub('2008-12-31', 1) = '2008-12-30'
```

You can even follow the link below.

https://www.qubole.com/resources/cheatsheet/hive-function-cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 9):

DATE_SUB is Available in HIVE 2.1.0

```
date_sub(date/timestamp/string startdate, tinyint/smallint/int days)
```

Subtracts a number of days to startdate: date_sub('2008-12-31', 1) = '2008-12-30'.

Prior to Hive 2.1.0 (HIVE-13248) the return type was a String because no Date type existed when the method was created.

Answer (score 6):

For versions >= Hive 2.0
Try this:

```
select current_date;
```

Then try this:

```
select date_sub(current_date, 1);
```

It should give you current date minus 1 day.

Answer (score 1):

If Hive version does not support `date_sub`, you can hack `date_add` and pass `-1` as the interval parameter.

```
select current_date as curr_date , date_add(current_date,-1) curr_minus_1;

curr_date  |  curr_minus_1  
2020-03-03 |  2020-03-02
```

Answer (score 0):

cast(date_sub(CURRENT_DATE, 1) as string)

Comment: You might want to add some more explanations or you might get your answer deleted.